# Conservation and potential with non-cartesian forces

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, conservative-field

I understand how to determine if a force is conservative from
\begin{equation}
\nabla\times \mathbf{F}=0 \implies \mathbf{F}\text{ is conservative}
\end{equation}
When $F$ is in cartesian coordinates.
What happens if you’re given a force such as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}=r\sin\theta e^{i\phi}\hat{r}
\end{equation}
How do you compute the curl and potential?

Answer (score 1):

The curl of any vector $\vec{F}$ in spherical polar coordinates is:
$$
\nabla \times \vec{F}  =  \frac{1}{r\sin \theta}\left(\frac{\partial (F_\phi
  \sin \theta) }{\partial \theta} -
                   \frac{\partial F_\theta}{\partial \phi}\right)\,\hat{\boldsymbol r} +
                   \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{1}{\sin \theta}
                   \frac{\partial F_r}{\partial \phi} - \frac{\partial
                     (r F_\phi)}{\partial r}\right)\,
                   \hat{\boldsymbol \theta} + \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial (
r
                     F_\theta)}{\partial r} -
                   \frac{\partial F_r}{\partial \theta}\right)\,
                   \hat{\boldsymbol \phi} \ .
$$
To "compute the potential" you would have to solve the equation
$$ \nabla V = -\vec{F}\ , $$
which, in spherical polar coordinates for a force which only has a $\hat{r}$ component, gives three equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} & = & -F_r \\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta} & = & 0 \\
\frac{1}{r\sin \theta}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
The potential is not uniquely determined because you can add any scalar field with a zero gradient to $V$.